# css for android browser and firefox

Tags: android, css, firefox, browser

I'm using a Wordpress responsive theme and would like a fixed background.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center; 
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I have found that the site  doesn't display correctly (only background seen, body content flashes up briefly) in Android browser and Dolphin,if I change the background to

```
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-attachment: scroll;
```

and add

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

This allows the body content to be seen but then on Firefox (android) you can't scroll down the page to see all the content. On other browsers the scroll is slow.
Is there a way to use a fixed background that will display ok on all(most) mobile phone browsers ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Code a litlle short to understand more of what's going next, inside body html structure and it's CSS